# Add another series to row Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to add another series to the row in this Highcharts example.

http://jsfiddle.net/norcalknockout/9xg3agc1/16/

I tried adding another task object, but that just creates another row.

I would like to have multiple series in the Category 1 row.

Thanks.

Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify a bit current logic, see live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9xg3agc1/19/

And explanation:

1. To each **task** add `categoryIndex`. If you want to use first category (which means `y=0`) with n-series, then calculate difference for each of the series. Category with `value = X` is rendered with y-values range: `X - 0.5` to `X + 0.5`. For example, if category index equals 0, and you want to display three series, then `categoryIndex` for those **tasks** can be `-0.33`, `0` and `+0.33`. With two categories you can use `-0.25` and `0.25` (like in the demo).
2. Change how `y` value is applied to the points. Right now `y` value is the same as **task** index in the `tasks` array. So, there should be value from `categoryIndex`, like this:

   ```
   y: task.categoryIndex,
   ```

And code sample:

```
// Define tasks
var tasks = [{
    categoryIndex: -0.25,
  name: 'Category 1',
  intervals: [{
    from: Date.UTC(2011, 05, 16),
    to: Date.UTC(2012, 03, 21)
  }, {
    from: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 09),
    to: Date.UTC(2015, 05, 22)
  }]
}, {
    categoryIndex: 0.25,
  name: 'Category 2',
  intervals: [{
    from: Date.UTC(2011, 05, 16),
    to: Date.UTC(2012, 03, 21)
  }, {
    from: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 09),
    to: Date.UTC(2015, 05, 22)
  }]
}];
```

Changes in logic:

```
    item.data.push({
      x: interval.from,
      y: task.categoryIndex, // use pre-calculated index
      label: interval.label,
      from: interval.from,
      to: interval.to
    }, {
      x: interval.to,
      y: task.categoryIndex, // use pre-calculated index
      from: interval.from,
      to: interval.to
    });
```